# Proper error handling using async/await in Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have the following code in my Node.js express app:

```
router.route('/user')

   .post(async function(req, res) {
       if(req.body.password === req.body.passwordConfirm) {
           try {
               var response = await userManager.addUser(req.body);
               res.status(201).send();
           } catch(err) {
               logger.error('POST /user failed with error: '+err);
               res.status(500).send({err:"something went wrong.."});
           }
       } else {
           res.status(400).send({err:'passwords do not match'});
       }
   })
```

and userManager:

```
var userManager = function() {

    this.addUser = async function(userobject) {
        userobject.password_hash = await genHash(userobject.password_hash);
        var user = new User(userobject);
        return await user.save();
    };

};

module.exports = userManager;
```

My question is: Will the try catch block in the route catch all errors thrown in *addUser* or will it only catch the ones that are thrown by *user.save()*, since that is the one that gets returned?

Comment: `addUser` is an `async function` and therefore *never throws an exception*. It only will return a promise that might be rejected.

Comment: Only if you `await` your `addUser` call...

Comment: Ah, nice catch, I forgot to add it there!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is yes, it will catch all the errors inside `try` block and in all internal function calls.

`async/await` is just syntax sugar for promises. Thus if something is possible using promises then it is also possible using `async/await`.

For example both of the following code snippets are equivalent:

Using promises:

```js
function bar() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('Uh oh!'));
}

function foo() {
  return bar();
}

function main() {
  return foo().catch(e => {
    console.error(`Something went wrong: ${e.message}`);
  });
}

main();
```

Using `async/await`:

```js
async function bar() {
  throw new Error('Uh oh!');
}

async function foo() {
  await bar();
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await foo();
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(`Something went wrong: ${e.message}`);
  }
}

main();
```

---

In fact your code will not work since you don't use `await` on `userManager.addUser`.

It also forces you to use `async` on the parent function and that may break things up. Check express documentation (or just try if it works).

```
router.route('/user')

   .post(async function(req, res) {
       if(req.body.password === req.body.passwordConfirm) {
           try {
               var response = await userManager.addUser(req.body);
               res.status(201).send();
           } catch(err) {
               logger.error('POST /user failed with error: '+err);
               res.status(500).send({err:"something went wrong.."});
           }
       } else {
           res.status(400).send({err:'passwords do not match'});
       }
   })
```

Comment: But OP does *not* use `await` inside the `try` block?!